# Encoding(?) error while trying to read a CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I'm opening a CSV file in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with LibreOffice and gedit, and in both apps I can see the file OK.

I've tried in a lot of ways to read that file into R using `read.csv()` but it is replacing the blank spaces `" "` for dots `"."`, among other strange things with characters different from letters.

I've tried with

```
codepages <- setNames(iconvlist(), iconvlist())
x <- lapply(codepages, function(enc) try(read.csv("ticket.csv", fileEncoding=enc)))
```

But it is always failing no matter which encoding I insert.

**EDIT:**

Here I send you the file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1P26eyiBDcNWWR0OGJwU0E4V00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(in a linux shell)

```
$ enca -f -L none ticket_import_template.csv
7bit ASCII characters

$ file ticket_import_template.csv
ticket_import_template.csv: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Looks like plain ASCII. In R:

```
dplyr::glimpse(read.csv("ticket_import_template.csv", check.names=FALSE))

## Observations: 1
## Variables:
## $ Ticket Number                             (lgl) NA
## $ *Open Date                                (fctr) 01/08/15 11:00
## $ 1st Response Date                         (lgl) NA
## $ Due Date                                  (lgl) NA
## $ Close Date                                (lgl) NA
## $ Status Type                               (lgl) NA
## $ Client (user name)                        (int) 950000
## $ Localizaci?n                              (lgl) NA
## $ *Request Type (semicolon delimited)       (fctr) Instalaciones
## $ Priority Type                             (lgl) NA
## $ Subject                                   (lgl) NA
## $ *Request Detail                           (fctr) PROBANDO
## $ Tech Username                             (lgl) NA
## $ Recurso Numbers                           (lgl) NA
## $ Notes                                     (lgl) NA
## $ Room                                      (lgl) NA
## $ Department                                (lgl) NA
## $ Tecnico asignado                          (lgl) NA
## $ Delete? (Y/N)                             (lgl) NA
## $ NOTE: * = Field required for new records. (lgl) NA
```

You can also just use:

- `readr::read_csv("ticket_import_template.csv")`
- `rio::import("ticket_import_template.csv")`
- `data.table::fread("ticket_import_template.csv")`

as well since their defaults are to leave the spaces (and more) in header column names.

`read.csv` adding sane `.`'s to the column headers since they have spaces in them. You'll actually end up regretting either spaced (as you'll get with `check.names == FALSE`) or dotted column names that long. The first thing you should probably do is rename the columns.

Comment: Really good answer. Thank you. The only thing is that the columns must be the same, immutable. This is required for another software (The ticket's DB) to work. Simply with `check.names == FALSE` seems to work. let's try it.